# Word meaning excess pieces of fabric

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

There’s a word I’m trying to recall, it means something such as “extra pieces of fabric hanging from clothing.” I believe it ends with *-gibles* or *-gables*, and perhaps it starts with *im-* or *ex-*, and it’s a noun. I’ve spent the last hour trying to figure it out.

Comment: Are you after a word for extra bits that are added as embellishment? Or pieces that are coming off due to it becoming worn? I'm guessing the former, but never hurts to check..

Comment: Haberdasher-it-all!  This question does need to be clarified a bit.  After all, you could looking for an obscure word meaning very ornate embellishments, like the [hoods](http://www.capsandgownsnow.com/hoodpics/academic_hood.jpg)  on graduation gowns, or you could just be looking for the word [fringe](http://hideandsoul.com/images/Fringe%20Jacket%20back%20Julie.jpg).  Either one qualifies as "extra pieces of fabric hanging from clothing."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't deserve any points for answering my own question, let alone a such a vague one. I finally realised the word I was trying to figure out was *accoutrements*.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I can think of is *fandangle*, which describes an embellishment or ornament that is used simply for decoration and has no other purpose.